# After applied as rest position mesh doesn't move

Tags: rigify

I'm really new to blender and english isn't my native language so i'll try to be as clear as possible. I'm making an animation for an university exam, i made a simple videogame character that i'm going to animate.

The character is an archer so he got a rigged bow and arrows as props; he wears a shirt, a vest, trousers, gloves and boots. All of them are different elements, i didn't joined the wearing stuff because i thought it could have been more simple to manage and edit the single elements.

After i used the Rigify Modifier i tried to put him in an idle position and when i had done it  i had accidentally applied the pose as rest pose. Since then, the only thing that moved was the rig but the mesh seems to stand still and even if i try to move the rig in pose mode it doesn't move.

There are many question that i would like to do, but essentially: Why the meshes doesn't move along with the rig anymore? And where i can find that bloody rest pose!? (I just selected "Apply as rest pose" because i was thinking maybe that was the only way to make that position the default pose in viewport and a good starting pose for my animation)

Comment: Your rig may still be in pose mode. Click on your rig, and go to the armature menu to change it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have nothing to loose, delete and regenerate your rig.

When i reset my rig i select all the bones and then

Select all the bones, in pose mode with A. Then, hit:

ALT R to reset all rotations,
ALT G to reset all translations,
ALT S to reset all scales.

Or select all bones (A) and hit space. Then search for "clear pose"